# Hadoop Mapper not running my class

Tags: hadoop

Using Hadoop version 0.20.. I am creating a chain of jobs job1 and job2 (mappers of which are in x.jar, there is no reducer) , with dependency and submitting to hadoop cluster using JobControl. Note I have setJarByClass and getJar gives the correct jar file, when checked before submission.

Submission goes through and there seem to be no errors in user logs and jobtracker. But I dont see my Mapper getting executed (no sysouts or log output), but default output seems to be coming to the output folder (input file is read as is and output). I am able to run the job directly using x.jar, but I am really out of clues as to why it is not running with Jobcontrol.

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

This issue bugged me for quite some days. Finally I found that it was the `UsedGenericOptionsParser` which created the issue. Set this to `true` and everything started working fine.